# How to write response into label box

Tags: php, html

I have a flat file TestFile.txt that has about 40 lines of data, each item on a separate row, so 40 lines.  I have a PHP code that finds the row containing a string I want to find using using $Search_String.  Then displays only the row containing $Search_String.  This works exactly as I want.  However; it displays the result in text area.  How do I display the result into a label box?

Here is part of my flat file, filename is TestFile.txt:

```
RXFrequency=432675000
TXFrequency=432675000
RXOffset=260
TXOffset=120
Network=mnet.hopto.org
Password=8Yg81xrqK0313zt
Latitude=34.657783
Longitude=-3.784595
Port=62021
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
// Place text to look for in string $Search_String.
// The $Search_String will remain hard coded in my production
// code. The users will not be able to select $Search_String.
$Search_String = "Lon";
// Identify Text File, open File and Read the File.
$MyFile = fopen("TestFile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$found= "False";
// Create the while loop.  Test each line with the if statement,
// looking for $Search_String, and place the result into string $line.
// Next, echo string $line which containes the found line in the 
// flat text file.  It will return the entire line even from a 
// partial $Search_String, which is what I want.
while ( $line = fgets( $MyFile ) )
  {
     if ( str_contains( $line, $Search_String ) ) 
     {
     echo $line;
     break;
     }
  }
// If the string $Search_String was not found, show a message
if(!$found)
{
  echo 'No match found';
}

// Properly close the text file.
fclose($MyFile);
?>
```

The PHP code above returns:

```
Longitude=-3.784595
```

Just what I want, but I need it displayed in text box, or label box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the answer as html

```
<?php
// Place text to look for in string $Search_String.
// The $Search_String will remain hard coded in my production
// code. The users will not be able to select $Search_String.
$Search_String = "Lon";
// Identify Text File, open File and Read the File.
$MyFile = fopen("TestFile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$found= "False";
// Create the while loop.  Test each line with the if statement,
// looking for $Search_String, and place the result into string $line.
// Next, echo string $line which containes the found line in the 
// flat text file.  It will return the entire line even from a 
// partial $Search_String, which is what I want.
while ( $line = fgets( $MyFile ) )
  {
     if ( str_contains( $line, $Search_String ) ) 
     {
     echo "<div style="
    border: double;
">".$line."</div>";
     break;
     }
  }
// If the string $Search_String was not found, show a message
if(!$found)
{
  echo 'No match found';
}

// Properly close the text file.
fclose($MyFile);
?>
```

Comment: The answer above throws an error.   Trying to send result to html.  How to send the string contained in $line to  a  input type="text" box.

Comment: Instead of div you will change to input

Comment: Changed to input.  I cannot get the code to execute.

Comment: Edit the first post with your revised code and I'll see why it does not work